# Keras to build a CNN with variable input size

Tags: nlp, keras, conv-neural-network

I would like to build a CNN from the following diagram

[image: CNN]

I presume that each time the sentence can have various lengths and it is still possible to build it.

The below is a something I found on the web but kind of got lost

```
ngram_filters = [2, 3, 4]
conv_filters = []

for n_gram in ngram_filters:
    conv_filters.append(Sequential())
    conv_filters[-1].add(Conv2D(1, 1, n_gram, 5))
    conv_filters[-1].add(MaxPooling2D(poolsize=(nb_tokens - n_gram + 1, 1)))
    conv_filters[-1].add(Flatten())

model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge(conv_filters, mode='concat'))
```

The picture comes from the following blog - http://www.wildml.com/2015/11/understanding-convolutional-neural-networks-for-nlp/

Comment: Take a look at this article - https://richliao.github.io/supervised/classification/2016/11/26/textclassifier-convolutional/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a variable input size, you just need to pad your input with zeros (make sure to mask these zeros). You can define your input size as a really big one and just pad the difference between each sentence length and the input size.

There is a built function in Keras', you can find it in [Sequence Preprocessing](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/) and the function is "pad_sequences". Make sure your model is aware of the padding value by masking these values using the [Masking class](https://keras.io/layers/core/).

You can see an example of the implementation [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2819).